# PyQt Freezing while many graphs plotting

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, pyqtgraph

```py
def initPlots(self):
    print("init_Plots")
    for S in range(self.sensor_num):
        globals()["self.plot{0}".format(S)] = pg.PlotWidget()
        globals()["self.plot{0}".format(S)].setYRange(-30,30)
        self.layout.addWidget(globals()["self.plot{0}".format(S)],S//5,S%5)


def showPlot(self,number,x_axis):
    print("init_showPlot")
    '''x_axis : time(s) / y_axis : data(rgb)'''
    globals()["self.plot{0}".format(number)].clear()
    globals()["self.plot{0}".format(number)].plot(x=x_axis,y=self.y_domain_r[number],
                                                  pen=pg.mkPen(width=2,color='r'),name="sensor_"+str(number)) # R
    globals()["self.plot{0}".format(number)].plot(x=x_axis,y=self.y_domain_g[number],
                                                  pen=pg.mkPen(width=2,color='g'),name="sensor_"+str(number)) # G
    globals()["self.plot{0}".format(number)].plot(x=x_axis,y=self.y_domain_b[number],
                                                  pen=pg.mkPen(width=2,color='b'),name="sensor_"+str(number)) # B


@QtCore.pyqtSlot(np.ndarray)
def run(self, arr):
    print("init_run(plot)")
    self.time += 1
    self.data = arr
    self.t_domain.append(self.time)
    for S in range(self.sensor_num):
        self.y_domain_r[S].append(self.data[S][0])
        self.y_domain_g[S].append(self.data[S][1])
        self.y_domain_b[S].append(self.data[S][2])
        self.showPlot(S,self.t_domain)
```

This is a program that receives the rgb change value of an image every frame and displays a graph for that value.
`np.ndarray` of delta RGBs Signal -> Slot

This program often shuts down when I press run. How to reduce memory usage?
Is that okay with that I'm using many `globals()`?

Is it an inevitable flaw in Python?

help me guys~

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who see this, I delete my globals and I made a plot list.
It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).